# Supabse check if user is connected expo-router

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, supabase, expo-router

How to use the supabase and expo-router authentication system to check that the user is logged in on the Index.tsx page before performing other functions, otherwise redirecting him to the Login.tsx page.

I use expo-router v2 and Supabase and here is my _layout.tsx

```js
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";

export default function TabRoutes() {
  return (
    <Tabs>
      <Tabs.Screen name="index" options={{ title: 'Index', headerShown: false }} />
      <Tabs.Screen name="login" options={{ title: 'Login', headerShown: false }} />
    </Tabs>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root `_layout.tsx`, you can detect changes to the path and redirect accordingly. Alternatively, you can use React Context to pass down the current authentication state.

Expo has documentation for authentication here: https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/authentication/#modals-and-per-route-authentication

Answer (score 0):

In your index.tsx you can do this

```
      return session && session.user ? (
    <Redirect href={"/(tabs)/"} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect href={"/(auth)/login"} />
  );
```

Grab the session and the session.user from supabase and have it redirect to the right spot.

This example here is using expo-router v3